# How to refetch until certain value is returned from the server? (React-Apollo)

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

With React-Apollo, is it possible to refetch again until the fetched data has a certain value?

Say I have a component who keeps pinging the server until the server gives back a certain response.

```
graphql(gql`
  query {
    ping {
      response
    }
  }
`)(MyComponent)
```

The server either returns

```
ping: {
  response: "busy"
}
```

or

```
ping: {
  response: "OK"
}
```

I want this component to keep pinging the server every one second (polling) until the response is "OK". What is the easiest way to do it with Apollo?

Answer (score 5):

Basically all you need to do is set up a query with an option `pollInterval` and when you get the wanted response call the `stopPolling` function that arrives on the `data` in the `props` function. And make sure the `fetchPolicy` is set to `'network-only'` that is compatible with polling.

Read about [options.pollInterval here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-config-options-pollInterval), about [options.fetchPolicy here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy) and about [the structure of the data prop here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#default-result-props).

This code should work for you:

```
const PingQuery = gql`
  query {
    ping {
      response
    }
  }
`

graphql(PingQuery, {
    options: {
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only', // we don't want to get the response from the cache
        pollInterval: 1000 // in milliseconds,      
    },
    props: ({data: {loading, ping, stopPolling}) => {
        if (loading) {
            return // still loading, ping is undefined
        }
        if (ping.response === 'busy') {
            // still busy
            return
        }       
        // not busy.. stop polling and do something
        stopPolling()
    }
})(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 1):

I may not have a perfect answer but I may have something to point you in the right direction.

The graphql() higher order component, as you are probably aware, takes a second parameter of options. You can specify things like a polling interval to continually repeat the query.

In this article, they explain how they were able to dynamically change this polling interval based on specific conditions.

https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/dynamic-graphql-polling-with-react-and-apollo-client-fb36e390d250

The example is using the recompose library, but I imagine you could do something similar like this.

```js
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { compose, withState, lifecycle } from "recompose";

const QUERY = gql`
  query {
    ping {
      response
    }
  }
`;

const withPing = compose(
  withState("polling", "setPolling", true),
  graphql(
    QUERY,
    {
      options: props => {
        if (props.polling === true) {
          return {
            pollInterval: 1000 // Repeat query every 1 second
          };
        } else {
          return { } // or return nothing
        }
      }
    }
  ),
  lifecycle({
    componentWillReceiveProps({
      data: { loading, ping },
      polling,
      setPolling
    }) {
      if (loading) {
        return;
      }

      if (ping.response === 'OK') {
        return setPolling(false) // Stops polling
      } else if (ping.response === 'busy') {
        return setPolling(true) // Continues polling
      }
    }
  })
);

const ComponentWithPing = withPing(Component);
```

I don't know if this would acctually work, but it should be close.

Another avenue you could checkout is the data.refetch() method on the data response object.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-query-data-refetch.

Best of luck!

You can read more about the options here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-query-options and specifically the pollInterval here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-config-options-pollInterval

Comment: the 1st url now 404s

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Subscriptions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/).

Example with Hooks:

```js
useSubscription(
  gql`
    subscription {
      ping {
        response
      }
    }
  `
)
```

And of course, the `useSubscription` Hook accepts a second parameter for options, so you could set your arguments like this:

```js
useSubscription(YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION, { variables: { foo: bar } })
```